# ncurses Won't Recognize arrow key macros

Tags: c, curses

I've been trying to find a solution to this for quite a while; I cannot get my terminal window to recognize the keypad.

Here is my code:

```
  while (1){
    if (cmd != ERR) {
      printw("Controls: LEFT/RIGHT and SPACEBAR (Q TO QUIT)");
      if (cmd == ' '){
         // Stuff
      }
      else if (cmd == KEY_LEFT){
         // Stuff
      }
      else if (cmd == KEY_RIGHT){
         // Stuff
      }
      else if (cmd == 'q'){
         // Stuff
      }
      refresh();
    }
    cmd = getchar();
  }
```

It recognizes that I am entering space (case 1) or "q" (case 4), but it will not recognize the built in curses macros. I'm using regular C, not C++ for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: getchar is a wrong function to use with ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

Those constants are only returned by `getch()` if you enable the keypad.

The function signature is:

```
int keypad(WINDOW *win, bool bf)
```

`keypad(win, true)` enables the keypad and `keypad(win, false)` disables it. `win` is a pointer to the window where `getch()` is being called.

Comment: Likely the OP is just using `getch()` without passing a `WINDOW` pointer, so `keypad(stdscr,TRUE)` would be the usual recommendation.  Note that curses defines "TRUE" rather than "true" (the two happen to be equal if ncurses is properly configured).

Comment: I am using `keypad(stdscr, TRUE)` and it still doesn't have any effect on recognizing the arrow keys. I've tried passing both TRUE and true to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Alexandre Bell, keypad has to be enabled. Enable it for the default window or the window you are working with.

```c
keypad(stdscr, TRUE); //Enables keypad for default window
```

If you are still having trouble getting it to work, make sure you are using an int datatype with getch(). The function prototype for getch() is:

```c
int getch(void);
```

If you are using a char datatype for the return value of getch(), then it will not be large enough to fit the return value of special characters and you will get garbage values back.